# trigger('click') inside setInterval()

Tags: javascript

i have this code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.button2').trigger('click');
    $('.button3').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

result:

it presses .button2 and .button3 at the same time every 5 seconds. I need something like this - 5 seconds passed press .button2, 5 seconds passed press .button3, need a delay between each button clicks and when .button3 is pressed - again press .button2 (something like a loop).

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT for flesk:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.goluboi a').click(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.videos .cover').animate({left:-875*(parseInt(integer)-1)})  /*----- Width of div mystuff (here 160) ------ */
        $('.goluboi a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        triggerClick('.button', 0)
    }, 5000);
    function triggerClick(selector, index) {
        var buttons = $(selector);
        var mod = index++ % buttons.length;
        $(buttons[mod]).trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function() {
            triggerClick(selector, index);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Same here. You're lucky you got this many answers Heihachi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    triggerClick('.button2');
}, 5000);

function triggerClick(selector) {
    $(selector).trigger('click');
    selector = (selector == '.button2') ? '.button3' : '.button2';
    setTimeout(function() {
        triggerClick(selector);
    }, 5000);
}
```

**EDIT:** Answer to your comment below:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    triggerClick('.button', 0)
}, 5000);

function triggerClick(selector, index) {
    var buttons = $(selector);
    var mod = index++ % buttons.length;
    $(buttons[mod]).trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
        triggerClick(selector, index);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Works for any number of buttons, as long as they all have the same class. There's no need to call them 'button1', 'button2' and 'button3' anyway. That's what id's are for.

**EDIT2:**

If I understand your update correctly, what you want is:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    triggerClick('.goluboi a.button', 0)
}, 5000);
function triggerClick(selector, index) {
    var buttons = $(selector);

    // Your logic
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.videos .cover').animate({left:-875*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
    $(buttons).removeClass('active');

    var mod = index++ % buttons.length;

    $(buttons[mod]).addClass('active').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
        triggerClick(selector, index);
    }, 5000);
}
});
```

Comment: function triggerClick(selector) - without var. Not working... :( Stucks on .button2 then not moving further.

Comment: look at ruh.kz
What if there's 5 buttons?

Comment: @Heihachi: See modified answer.

Comment: now i called all buttons .button. Take a look at ruh.kz now please. Some problem with class .active when trigger('click') happens

Comment: I don't see anything like that there. Maybe you should just put the relevant code into a jsfiddle?

Comment: look at my edited question please. As u can see there, when u press a button it gets class .active, and if you click another button then that button gets class .active and the last one loses this class. How can i implement that in your code? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: thanks, check now ruh.kz. Now buttons gets class active at the right way, but the slide is not sliding anymore :) Really appreciate your help, could you please edit your code to make it work?

Comment: and i've forgot - in my old code user could click button by hisself too, could we save that functional? Manual click on buttons and autoclicking in time interval?

Answer (score 3):

you could do this with setTimeout

```
function a() {
    $('.button2').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(b, 5000);
}
function b() {
    $('.button3').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(a, 5000);
}
setTimeout(a, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ugly but it works.

```
var clickButton = false;

setInterval(function() {
    if( clickButton ) {
        clickButton = false;
        $('.button2').trigger('click');
    } else {
        clickButton = true;
        $('.button3').trigger('click');
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answers already posted.  Here's another:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.button2').trigger('click');
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.button3').trigger('click');
    }, 10000);
}, 5000);
```

This starts the first interval immediately and the second interval after 5 seconds, with the end result that two intervals are running every 10 seconds, but offset by 5 seconds.